# On alert button click stop counter

Tags: angular, ionic2

i have this code and i want it to stop the countdown when the user clicks yes/ no in the alert message. i am new with ionic so i appreciate the help! thank you !

ts :

```
   let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'EMERGENCY ALERT!!!',
        subTitle: 'Call Emergency Contact ?!',
              buttons: [
    {
      text: 'NO, I am Okay',
      handler: () => {
          console.log('NO, I am Okay');
      }
    },
    {
      text: 'YES Call',
      handler: () => {
          console.log('YES Call');
      }
    }
              ],
              enableBackdropDismiss: false
    });
   alert.present();

   this.counter = 10;
   window.clearInterval(this.timer);
   this.timer = setInterval(() => {
       this.counter--;
       if (this.counter === 0) {
           window.clearInterval(this.timer);

           /*After counter value is 0 means 10000 is completed */
           this.startFilling();
       }
   }, 1000);
}

startFilling() {
    console.log(true);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean to stop the timer or pause the timer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both buttons' handler, call `clearInterval` passing the timer to stop the timer.

```
handler: () => {
            console.log('NO, I am Okay');
            clearInterval(this.timer) 
          }
```